# Compiler directives greyout Visual Studio Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am developing a multiplatform Xamarin application with SAP. The compiler directives are greyed out.

[image]

[image]

What else I can do?

Comment: First do not use images for code, it is non-searchable, hard to read, etc... cut/paste your code elements. Second you are only defining `_ANDROID_` and not `WINDOWS_UWP` and since your `_ANDROID_` ifdef is ***inside*** of a `WINDOWS_UWP` ifdef, they are both greyed out.

Comment: Besides what SushiHangover mentioned, what kind of project are you using the compiler directives in? Seems you changed the compilation symbols in your android project, I think you may need to add these two symbols in your shared project.